# LEAD/LAG Functions

Tags: sql, hana

I need help coming with an optimized SQL.  I'm thinking of using LEAD function but I'm not sure...

```
Article   YEARMONTH   TYPE
123        201612      Z
123        201701      A
456        201703      B    
123        201702
123        201703      AA
456        201704      
456        201705      BB
```

I need to take the type from previous period only for those records where TYPE is not populated.

```
Article   YEARMONTH   TYPE
123        201612      Z
123        201701      A
456        201703      B    
123        201702      A - Take from Previous YEARMONTH(In this case its 201701) 
123        201703      AA
456        201704      B   - This is from 201703
456        201705      BB
```

This is what I get:

[image: Issue -If we use COALESCE and LAG]

Comment: You have an idea of what direction to go. Share the attempt you made using LEAD please.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

`lag()` is the way to go:

```
select . . .,
       coalesce(type, lag(type) over (partition by article order by yearmonth))
from t;
```

Don't worry about this executing for every row.  That is not how SQL works.  Instead, be sure you have an index on `(article, yearmonth)` for performance.

Comment: I'm running into an issue if the previous record is null as well -In that case i have to go one month prior ..I have to find  non null prior YEAR MONTH values

Answer (score 0):

@SQL3026, could you please try following SQL CTE expression on your sample data

Just a few notes;

LEAD and LAG does not simply provide a solution for taking NOT NULL values

I used self-JOIN (although you did not mention, from Gordon's query I thought there is also a criteria of having the same article value for fetching the previous type) and used all criterias at ON condition of the JOIN

For calculating previous month, I sorted rows using [SQL ROW_NUMBER() function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-row_number-over-partition-by-order-by.aspx)

CTE expression mainly filters outcome of JOIN using row_number value = 1 for previous month of each row

COALESCE) function returns first non-null value. In this case, it only detect most earliest article entry and shows its TYPE column values instead of showing NULL

```
with cte as (
select 
    t1.article,
    t1.yearmonth,
    t1.type,
    t2.type as prev_type,
    row_number() over (partition by t1.article, t1.YEARMONTH order by t2.YEARMONTH desc) as rn
from article_types as t1
left outer join article_types as t2
    on t1.article = t2.article
    and t2.TYPE is not null
    and t2.yearmonth < t1.yearmonth
order by t1.article, t1.YEARMONTH, t2.YEARMONTH
)
select
    article, yearmonth, type, coalesce(prev_type, type) as prev_type
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Output is as follows

[image]